# Vertical spring spacer CSS

Tags: css

I'm new here at stack **overflow**. :-)

How can I create a div that automatically change it's height to get all the space filled?
I've tried with
`height:"auto"`
but doesn't work... :(

For example:

```
<div style="height:300px">
    <div style="height:50px">...</div>
    <div>The height of this div varies from page to page...</div>
    <div style="height:???">SPROING!!</div>
    <div style="height:50px">...</div>
</div>
```

EDITED the example to match better my needings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a pure CSS way to do it since what you're trying to do is:

```
spring height = parent height - n children's height
```

You can do it pretty easily with some jQuery though:

**Markup**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top">...</div>
    <div id="spring">SPROING!!</div>
    <div id="bottom">...</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var leftover = $('#parent').height() - $('#top').height() - $('#bottom').height();
$('#spring').height(leftover);
```

In [action here](http://jsfiddle.net/kH46S/).

Comment: thanks a lot!
i've created a function and when the body loads or resizes it will update the spring's height, and it works nicely! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a container div (like in the example there) you can set it to a fixed height (in the example, 250px).  But if you do not know the height of the div's container, but do know the height of it's sibling containers, you could try setting the height to 100% and giving it padding of whatever the divs above and below have for heights.

Comment: thanks, but the problem also is that I know every elements' height except one... :(
I thought that there were an universal solution...
(I'll change the example to match this)